# how can i call the model in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db-table

[Here is my code](http://pastebin.com/iytPWzRz)

now in line no 75 to 104 for using transactions connection, i create an individual model transactions like this

```
<?php

class Application_Model_DbTable_Transactions extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
    {


           public function transactions {

                            $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();      
                            $sSqlT1 = "Insert into transactions (txnId, txnDateTime, partnerId, pointsProgramId, points, extTxnId) VALUES (uuid(), now(), '$partnerId', '$pointsProgramId',$pointsNeeded, '$voucherid')";
                            $create_voucher_txn_stmt = $this->db->query($sSqlT1);
                            error_log(__FUNCTION__.' : line '.__LINE__.' : ' .$sSqlT1);

                            try{ // If transactions successfully added...
                                    $sSqlT2 = "select max(txnId) as txnId from transactions where extTxnId='$voucherid'";
                                    $select_Txn_stmt = $this->db->query($sSqlT2);
                                    $txnid_get_results = $select_Txn_stmt->fetchall();
                                    $txnId = $txnid_get_results['0']['txnId'];
                            }
                            catch(Exception $e){
                                    error_log('Exception in '.__FUNCTION__.' : line '.__LINE__.' : '.$e->getMessage());
                            }
                            return $txnId;

    }
```

I am missing `'$partnerId', '$pointsProgramId',$pointsNeeded, '$voucherid'` this parameter here in this model how can i call this here

and after creating this model i again want to call this in between 75 to 104 ???

I am trying this

```
$transa=new Application_Model_DbTable_Transactions;
$tResult = $trans->transactions();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php

class Application_Model_DbTable_Transactions extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    public function transactions( $partnerId, $pointsProgramId, $pointsNeeded, $voucherid )
    {
        $db     = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
        $sSqlT1 = "Insert into transactions (txnId, txnDateTime, partnerId, pointsProgramId, points, extTxnId) VALUES (uuid(), now(), '{$partnerId}', '{$pointsProgramId}', {$pointsNeeded}, '{$voucherid}')";

        $create_voucher_txn_stmt = $this->db->query($sSqlT1);

        error_log(__FUNCTION__.' : line '.__LINE__.' : ' .$sSqlT1); 

        try
        {
            $sSqlT2            = "select max(txnId) as txnId from transactions where extTxnId='{$voucherid}'";
            $select_Txn_stmt   = $this->db->query( $sSqlT2 );
            $txnid_get_results = $select_Txn_stmt->fetchall();
            $txnId             = $txnid_get_results['0']['txnId'];
        }
        catch ( Exception $e )
        {
            error_log('Exception in '.__FUNCTION__.' : line '.__LINE__.' : '.$e->getMessage() ); 
        }

        return $txnId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Zend provides more Rigid and easy to use way of handling db heres the quick and dirty

```
    class Application_Model_DbTable_Transactions extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
        {
         protected $_name = 'transactions'; //Or your table name

        public function transactions($partnerid,$pointsProgramId,$pointsNeeded,$voucherid) {
//The keys of the array $data must be your table headers...
$data = array('txnId' => uuid(),
             'txnDateTime' => now(),
              'partnerId' => partnerId,
              'pointsProgramId' => $pointsProgramId,
              'points' => $pointsNeeded,
              'extTxnId' => $voucherid
);
  $res = $this->insert($data);  

                               if($res){
                                      //Do your stuff here its inserted
                                }


        }
}
//Calling
$trans= new Application_Model_DbTable_Transactions();
$tResult = $trans->transactions($partnerid,$pointsProgramId,$pointsNeeded,$voucherid);
```